# Comparing parseInt(String) to Int input error: unexpected type Java

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, int, compare

I know this title sounds like the many like it, but I have spend over an hour trying to trouble shoot this with google and stack overflow.

I am trying to make a menu for the user to choose from, but when I input an option, it doesn't register as equal.

```
System.out.println("What would you like to do?\n1. Add\n2. End session");
String Selection = null;
Console reader;
        try{
            reader = System.console();
            if(reader != null){
                do{
                    Selection = reader.readLine("Please enter corresponding number: ");
                    if(((Integer.parseInt(Selection)) != 1) || ((Integer.parseInt(Selection)) != 2)){
                        System.out.println("Please enter a valid option");
                    }
                }while(((Integer.parseInt(Selection)) != 1) || ((Integer.parseInt(Selection)) != 2));
            }
        }catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
```

I have tried:

- `Selection.equals("1")`
- `Selection.equals("Add")`
- `"Add".equals(Selection)`
- `"1".equals(Selection)`

and I can't figure out what is wrong.  I figured if String to String comparison wasn't working, int would work, but it doesn't :(  When I compile and run the program, it is just stuck in the loop except in this last version with "parseInt" I can throw an exception to get out of the loop.

When I tried replacing the "!=" with "=" it gave me this error:

```
Checkbook.java:171: error: unexpected type
                                    }while(((Integer.parseInt(Selection)) = 
1) || ((Integer.parseInt(Selection)) != 2));
                                                             ^
required: variable
found:    value
1 error
```

Why am I getting this error, but not when I have "!=" and why does the if and do/while statements even execute if I enter whatever I put as an option.

Edit:
Oops, I totally spaced = vs. ==.  Once I fixed that problem, it ran as I would expect it to: it looped, which I don't want.  But if I use the !=, it also loops.  How come???

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, and `!=` is an equality operator. [They're not the same kind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: `((Integer.parseInt(Selection)) != 1) || ((Integer.parseInt(Selection)) != 2)` can never be false. Try `&&`.

Comment: @shmosel, Thanks, that worked!  I would just mark your comment as the answer, but I can't :(

Answer (score -1):

your logic is wrong.

try

```
!(Integer.parseInt(Selection) == 1 || Integer.parseInt(Selection) == 2)
```

or

```
Integer.parseInt(Selection) != 1 && Integer.parseInt(Selection) != 2
```

Comment: The answer was already provided in the comments. This seems to be little more than a copy of the answer in the comments.

Comment: I really don't see a reason to downvote. The question was answered. My answer was neither sloppy nor incorrect. The op can decide whether my answer was the one that helped him or not.